# How to make line thicker in shape file when using geopandas with python?

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas

I am using the shape file found here: https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f7f805eb65eb4ab787a0a3e1116ca7e5

When I plot it in ipython it looks as shown below.My goal is to add or make the state lines more visible so I know what state the point is showing up in.

[image]

Comment: where is the rest of your codes? also put it in text rather than image. what is geo_df_a? what is gpd? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the parameter "edgecolor".  This will highlight the state lines.

```
usa.plot(ax=ax, alpha=.4, color='gray', edgecolor='black')
```

Result:

[image]